# term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

Tags: c++

```
struct Color {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    Color(int nred, int ngree, int nblue):red(nred),green(ngree),blue(nblue){
    }
};

struct Cal {
    int days;
    Color color;
    Cal(): days(), color(255,255,255){
    }
};
int main() {
    Cal go;
    go.color(100,100,100);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem? Does Compiler think that `color` is function and not constructor? How to solve this?

Comment: Are you writing `go.color(100, 100, 100);` because you want to construct the color with 100, 100, 100 instead of 255, 255, 255?

Comment: The error is no match for call to `(Color) (int, int, int)'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it thinks that `color` is a function and not a constructor.

The object is already constructed, and it's too late to call the constructor.

## Option 1

Add a constructor to `Cal` that can take color values and forward them:

```
struct Cal {
    int days;
    Color color;
    Cal(): days(), color(255,255,255){
    }
    Cal(int nred, int ngree, int nblue): days(), color(nread,ngree,nblue){
    }
};
int main() {
    Cal go(100,100,100);
    return 0;
}
```

## Option 2

Manually set the values:

```
int main() {
    Cal go;
    go.color.red = go.color.green = go.color.blue = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

## Option 3

Assign the `color` member from a temporary instance:

```
int main() {
    Cal go;
    go.color = Color(100, 100, 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For option 1, why not have a constructor with all three values defaulted to `255`?

Comment: I wanted to give Option three as an answer, but found it easier to edit your's and add it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that should be `Color(100, 100, 100)` to match the OP's intent.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That would allow the constructor to be called with just a red value, leaving blue and green to be defaulted. This is hard to understand when reading, so a constructor that allows this is suboptimal interface design.